# What is the relationship between the verbal definition and the mathematical definition of some quantities?

Tags: electricity, definition, voltage

I know this is probably an easy question, but it's been a while since I've studied physics and  I've started reading some circuit analysis textbooks.

I'm finding hard to understand the relationship between between the verbal definition of quantites and the mathematical definitions. For instance, in the Sadiku's book "Fundamentals of electic circuits", I've got the following verbal definiton for voltaje (literal)

"Voltage (or potential difference) is the energy required to move a unit
charge through an element, measured in volts (V)."

And then, it says that this mathematically "means"

$$
v_{ab} \triangleq \frac{dw}{dq} 
$$

I can't understand well the relationship between this two "definitions" could someone explain further the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work required to move a charge $q$ between two locations $a$ and $b$ with a voltage difference $V_{ab}$ is 
$$w=V_{ab}q.$$
Differentiating with respect to $q$, one obtains
$$\frac{dw}{dq}=V_{ab},$$
which is how the book got the equation.

Basically, the intuition is that voltage is "work per charge moved".

Comment: Ahhhh well , it makes sense...
The books doens't explain it like that and it was not the only definition of that kind. Thanks.